# Pass Info to Client without Page Refresh in Asp.net MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, real-time

Today we have seen some sites that pass data or notification to client without page refresh. Named Real time or interactive applications.

some of known site are :

1. [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) : notifications
2. [Freelancer](http://freelancer.com) : passes project and professional counts asynchronously in  numeric format
3. [Google Mail](http://mail.google.com) : Counts mail memory usage by users in total.

and so more ... .

I have tried and searched some tools like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Basically [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) designed for creating chat application. But is there a direct way without any extension in Microsoft Technologies to meet our purpose? For example suppose we want a simple counter like [freelancer](http://freelancer.com), Have we no way except using extensions like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)?

Comment: To my understanding, SignalR is not designed for "chat application", it is pretty much exactly what you're looking for. Considering your stack is C#/ASP.NET MVC - that's a pretty good choice. That said, you can take a look at Socket.IO, which I believe has a C# client implementation as well.

Comment: I know too that SignalR is good tool, but have some features that is not needed for a simple data reflection.

Comment: SignalR is not just for chat applications, but since most people understand how a chat application should work, most examples use an easy-to-grasp chat application approach when demonstrating features. There is a sample SignalR stock ticker on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SignalR.Sample). Take a look at that to see SignalR in a non-chat implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at a technique called polling (which SignalR falls back to when support for other methods are not present), basically the concept is that every `x` seconds you'd send a request to the server to check for an update (more or less), for example (using jQuery):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("/Messages/GetCount", function(data) {
        // do something with the data ...
    });
}, 30000);
```

Every 30 seconds, check the Messages count - and perform an action accordingly. [Here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) is a good article on polling and long polling (it mentions a SignalR alternative called Socket.IO).

Having said all that, I'd seriously just go with SignalR, those guys tested all kinds of corner cases, performance etc.

Comment: You have suggested good solution but my question mainly refers to server ability(MVC power) to send data to client and client only has an script to show update only. any way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Javascript timer on the client-side to make periodic asynchronous requests for updated information. This updated information can then be used to update the client-side, or can be used to prompt further requests for more details.

This solution can work for situations where you do not need to receive immediate updates whenever there are updates available on the server side (but instead can wait for the timer interval). It also may present some scaling issues and can lead to wasting bandwidth and client/server time while making unnecessary calls.

To overcome either of these, it would be best to use a library like SignalR (which can do much more than just chat applications - check out [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/May/22/A-first-look-at-SignalR) for a real world implementation that has nothing to do with chat).

Comment: Good. But not an optimized solution that you mentioned it too.

Comment: Like I said, if you just want to update a counter on a screen, you can use a JavaScript timer (with or without jQuery or other frameworks to help) to query for new info on a given interval. For tiny updates like this, it might be what you are looking for and can help you to avoid needing to integrate a framework like SignalR. It does have its shortcomings though (which are for the most part are not present in SignalR).

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's ASP.NET Ajax implementation or JQuery:

[Microsoft Ajax Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)